# Method attribute of NoneType object

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm going through a tkinter tutorial, and I'm having a hard time understanding the `self.master.title()` call.  It seems like master is assigned a default value of `None` during construction.  `master` is then assigned to `self.master` thereby making self.master a `NoneType` object.   Where does the `self.master.title` attribute come from?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame):                         

    def __init__(self, master = None):          
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)         
        self.master = master 
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):      
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack()
```

Comment: You're right, if `Window` is instantiated without a value for `master` then `self.master.title` will fail with an AttributeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `master` does have a default value of `None` this default will only matter if no arguments were specified (i.e. `thing = Window()`).

If an argument is specified (i.e. `thing = Window(SomeTKinterObject)`) then `self.master` will be equal to the argument (in this case `SomeTKinterObject`).

Comment: Thank you -- that's right.  Arguments passed by position will override default function arguments with no need to match by name.